# How to correctly upload and get blobs google cloud python client library multithreadedly?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download mp3 file from a server and then upload to google storage with the following code

```
from google.cloud import storage
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucketname')
blob = bucket.blob(uploadKey)
blob.upload_from_filename(flacFileName)
```

But to be noted the downloads and uploads are multithreaded and in some of the  threads I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/tamim/upworkProjects/speech_recong/upload_to_storage.py", line 51, in downloadMp3AndUploadToBucket
    blob.upload_from_filename(flacFileName)
  File "/home/tamim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 719, in upload_from_filename
    file_obj, content_type=content_type, client=client)
  File "/home/tamim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 673, in upload_from_file
    connection.http, request, retries=num_retries)
  File "/home/tamim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/streaming/http_wrapper.py", line 384, in make_api_request
    redirections=redirections)
  File "/home/tamim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/streaming/http_wrapper.py", line 347, in _make_api_request_no_retry
    redirections=redirections, connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/tamim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/streaming/http_wrapper.py", line 107, in _httplib2_debug_level
    http.connections[connection_key].set_debuglevel(old_level)
KeyError: 'https:accounts.google.com'
```

I also get `[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2178)` exceptions. But those exceptions are erratic and also I have none of these problems if I don't use multiple threads. So, how do I correctly upload files to google storage multithreadedly ?

I have looked at this link https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1214 and here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety but I couldn't find answer of how to do it with `google-cloud-storage` client library.

Comment: May I know the reason for down-vote?

Comment: Unsure about the downvote, but do you create a separate storage client for each thread?  If you are sharing a single one across threads, I think the thread safety link you provided describes why you'd see this error.

Comment: Exactly, thanks !!! The idea of creating separate clients didn't occur to me. It works now. Thank you ...